# CStatusBarCtrl automatic resize

Tags: winapi, mfc

In MFC shouldn't a status bar resize automatically when the parent window updates?Is there a missing setting I need to use to make this happen?

```
class Mainwindow {
public:
    MainWindow() {
        Create(NULL, _T("Main Window"));
}
afx_msg int OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lp) {
        // Status bar
        CRect rc;
        this->GetClientRect(&rc);
        std::array<int, 3> sb = { rc.right / 3,rc.right / 3 * 2,-1 };
        status_bar.Create(WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | CCS_BOTTOM | SBARS_SIZEGRIP, CRect(0, 0, 0, 0), this, IDS_STATUSBARCTRL);
        status_bar.SetParts(3, sb.data());
        status_bar.SetTipText(1, _T("Tooltip text"));
        status_bar.SetText(_T("Left"), 0, SBT_POPOUT);
        status_bar.SetText(_T("Middle"), 1, 0);
        status_bar.SetText(_T("Right"), 2, 0);
        return TRUE;
    }

// This resizes the status bar fine, but shouldn't MFC handle it?
       afx_msg void OnSize(UINT, int cx, int cy) {
        status_bar.SendMessage(WM_SIZE, 0, 0);
    }

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()

private:
    CStatusBarCtrl status_bar;
};


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(MainWindow,CFrameWnd)
    ON_WM_CREATE()
    ON_WM_SIZE()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just scanning the MFC code... (can't get my debugger to step through at the moment, argh)

Inside the CFrameWnd class, there's a function called RecalcLayout. MSDN says:

*Called by the framework when the standard control bars are toggled on or off or when the frame window is resized.*

RecalcLayout makes a call to CWnd::RepositionBars. Inside the function is a comment:

```
// walk kids in order, control bars get the resize notification
//   which allow them to shrink the client area
```

It looks like the notification is done via the WM_SIZEPARENT message:

a) The CControlBar class has a message handler for WM_SIZEPARENT

b) CStatusBarCtrl is derived from CWnd, not CControlBar, and therefore won't get the message

Solution: I would just do it the way the app wizard does it - make your status bar member variable a CStatusBar. (derived from CControlBar) From there you can call GetStatusBarCtrl().

```
// .h
CStatusBar status_bar;

// .cpp
if (!status_bar.Create(this))
{
    TRACE0("Failed to create status bar\n");
    return -1;
}

auto& statusBarCtrl = status_bar.GetStatusBarCtrl();
statusBarCtrl.SetParts(3, sb);
// etc.
```

Comment: This works, but just for reference, you have to either remove the `WM_SIZE` handler completely and let MFC do all the updates itself or call `CFrameWnd::OnSize()` after any custom resizes

Answer (score 0):

I do have an alternative solution here that doesn't avoid using the `CStatusBarCtrl`. This is an old question, but if you are interested, continue reading:

If you observe carefully, whenever `CStatusBarCtrl` is created, its always knows its exact place on the parent window and disregard `cost RECT& rect` argument. So it has the capability to resize itself. You just have to wake it up while the parent window is resizing by calling the `CWnd::SetWindowPos` method in the `CStatusBarCtrl`. The argument can be all zero since `CStatusBarCtrl` ignores it anyway, it just needs to be reminded it needs re-positioning.

This is how you implement it:

Step 1: In the OnCreate() method of the parent window, create the `CStatusBarCtrl`:

```
int MainFrmWnd::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct) {
    if (CFrameWnd::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
        return -1;

    
    m_infoBar = new CStatusBar;
    m_infoBar->Create(WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | CCS_BOTTOM | SBARS_SIZEGRIP, 
                      CRect(), 0x1234);
    int partWidths[] = { 100, 200, -1 };
    m_infoBar->SetParts(3, partWidths);
    m_infoBar->SetText(_T("Pane 1..."), 0, NULL);
    m_infoBar->SetText(_T("Pane 2..."), 1, NULL);
    m_infoBar->SetText(_T("Pane 3..."), 2, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Step 2: In the parent window's WM_SIZE, poke the `CStatusBarCtrl` with `SetWindowPos`:

```
void MainFrmWnd::OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy) {
    CFrameWnd::OnSize(nType, cx, cy);

    // Parameter values don't matter,
    // This is just to remind CStatusBarCtrl it needs repositioning
    m_infoBar->SetWindowPos(&wndTop, 0, 0, 0, 0, NULL);
}
```

**Tested with VS2019**

[image]